# 60,000,000 records with $lookup and $out so slow

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

i have two collections

1. `orders` 5,000,000 record
2. `prices` 60,000,000 record

i made a simple aggregate on `orders` with `$lookup` `$out` stage
and it's really slow left it run for more than a day and still processing the query `created all the needed indexs` and nothing

`SERVER configuration`

- `RAM`: 400+GB
- `Storage`: SSD 1TB
- `CPU`: Xeon E5-02673 v4 2.30GHZ
- `OS`: Ubuntu 16